# wordpress Including categorys in search results

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to include categories in search results I've been google-ing for hours now with no solution.

Now by including categories i dont mean search in a certain category, i mean lets say i have a bicycle store and have many companies included in the site. A user searched for `BMX mountain cross..` for example. it will return the category BMX first(by clicking you'll be sent to category page) and the posts related to the search term like wordpress normally does.

Anyone has any clue or could point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin should do the trick
http://guff.szub.net/source/search-catname.php